# Swift Firebase Query from two nodes

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I have two nodes in my database: users and post. each time a new post is made the uid of the user is added to the post node. as shown below:

```
{
"users" : {
    "0dysOwZscHcwcq7EsRVapDMg8V03": {
        "firstName": "Yobo",
        "email": "Yobo@gmail.com"
    }
    "-23798gfoefcfe0f": {
        "firstName": "last",
        "email": "last@gmail.com"
    }
 }

}

{
"posts" : {
    "KUhyPi5xLZBGyp-_X-W": {
        "user": "0dysOwZscHcwcq7EsRVapDMg8V03",
        "comment": "I love this"
    }
    "-KWH8EVxohgNBfHuKoYy": {
        "user": "-23798gfoefcfe0f",
        "comment": "Coding is fun"
    }
 }
}
```

My challenge is this.  For instance I am able to get comments in the posts node which include the user who made the post. How can I then gather up all the user ids and go get those individual users first name in the users node